# indexOf method for array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have array of objets like:

```
var MyArray = [] ,
    Person = {}, 

[
    {
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Smith',
        age: '22'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jesica',
        surname: 'Garou',
        age: '31'
    },
    {
        name: 'Max',
        surname: 'Jolie',
        age: '50'
    }
]
```

I want to check , if my data has name 'John' that don't add new person , if not , then add new person with name 'John' and etc.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**

Comment: @charlietfl i create objets and pass it to array , but in this step i cand find any solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` but you have to know that map iterates through all elements in the array, whereas `findIndex` returns the first element index that equals the condition and stops the loop.

```js
var MyArray = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Smith',
        age: '22'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jesica',
        surname: 'Garou',
        age: '31'
    },
    {
        name: 'Max',
        surname: 'Jolie',
        age: '50'
    }
];

if(MyArray.findIndex(index => index.name === "John") > -1)
  console.log("Found!");
else
    console.log("Not found!");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could deal with it using `Array#find`. I assume that you want to mutate your original array.

```js
let arr = [{
    name: 'Jesica',
    surname: 'Garou',
    age: '31'
  },
  {
    name: 'Max',
    surname: 'Jolie',
    age: '50'
  }
];

const obj = {
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Smith',
  age: '22'
};

const ensure = ({ name, ...z }) => {
  if (!arr.find(v => v.name === name)) {
    arr.push({ name, ...z });
  }
}

ensure(obj);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I meant _map_ abstractly, not in the sense of the function, but rather that what would have an `undefined` result had a `null` substituted for it for no gain.

Comment: Definitely the best answer. It would be even better if `exist` was renamed to `ensure` and `==` was changed to `===` :)

Answer (score 2):

To check if a `name` already exists in an array, you can make use of `array.some` function. It will check if `name` provided already exits or not.

If not then you can write the code to push the object in the array.

I have used the sample names `John` and `Anne`. For `John`, the function `isAlreadyPresent` returns `true`. For `Anne`, it returns `false`.

```js
let arr = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Smith',
        age: '22'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jesica',
        surname: 'Garou',
        age: '31'
    },
    {
        name: 'Max',
        surname: 'Jolie',
        age: '50'
    }
];

function isAlreadyPresent(name) {
  return arr.some(a => a.name === name );
}

console.log('John already exists?',isAlreadyPresent('John'));
console.log('Anne already exists?',isAlreadyPresent('Anne'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through all of the objects and check each of their name values. At worst runs in O(n) time.

For example, to check if "John" is a name in the array:

```
var inArray = false; // Have we found the name in the array yet?
for (var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; i++) { // Loop through the array of objects
    if (MyArray[i].name=="John") { // If the name field is equal to "John"
        inArray = true; // Name is in the array
        break; // Exit the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi . There is no way without "for" ? its little bit slowly for my case.

Comment: @ArikDonowan well *something* has to iterate through the array; there's no magic. If you need faster access, you need a more sophisticated data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a name Map could be useful:

```
var byNam e =new Map(myArray.map(el=>[el.name,el]));
```

So you can easily do:

```
if (byName.has("John")){
  alert("already exists");
} else {
  var obj = { name: "John" };
  Map.set(obj.name,obj);
  myArray.push(obj);
}
```

The upper can be achieved with a Set also, but you may also want to do this:

```
byName.get("John").age=15;
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using `Map`. This does a lot of extra work and it introduces a parallel data structure that has to be kept up to date. The `byName` approach would be good if it was a function that always returned current the elements in the array by name.

Comment: @aluan haddad just because youre not seing the usecase is not a reason to give a downvote. If youre not understanding sth, it would be enough to ask...

Comment: That is true. I apologize for my rash behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchTerm = "John",
index = -1;
for(var i = 0, len = MyArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (MyArray[i].name === searchTerm) {
        alert("matched string");
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Also, make sure to format your code at the top.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a search function like this that:

```
const index = (array, name) => {
  // Search for the string "name" in your array
  for (let i in array){
    // Look at every element in the array, if an element has the
    // corresponding name, return its index
    if (array[i].name === name) return i;
  }
  return -1;
  // If you found nothing, return -1
}

let position = index(myArray, "John");
```

Comment: Don't use `for..in` on an `Array`.

Comment: With the new implementation of `for...in` in v8, it's actually the fastest method to do it:
[V8 for...in](https://v8project.blogspot.ch/2017/03/fast-for-in-in-v8.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/1915893. RE: V8 it is still awful code, also if you are going to base your rationale on the latest browser environments, use `find`.

Answer (score -2):

Traditionally we use a constructor to build many similar objects. However, how that is OOP and is out of the scope of what you are asking.

Here we can use a for... in loop to iterate though MyArray, and check that each object does not include the name John.

```
function addJohn () {
for (let iterator in MyArray) { // You can also use for... of, but it will break in Node.
     if (MyArray[iterator].name == "John") {return}; //You can also replace the string with a variable name to check that all objects do not have the variable in them.
     else continue;
}
// you can now put in your new object here.
}
```

Comment: *else continue* is useless

Comment: `for in` is not recommended with arrays